# WS_FTP Server - All Files Older Than 30 Days Show Date but NO Time Stamp

Tags: ftp, time-synchronization

Picture from FileZilla of the root of my FTP Server running WS_FTP Server 7.5.1.2 on Windows Server 2003x64 Standard sp2

[image]

Notice how the first file folder shows the date 8/24/2011 but no time and the second file folder shows 10/13/2011 3:26:00 AM, showing date and time.  For synchronization I need to have all elements show the date and the time, yet it appears any file older than 30 days the time is no longer reported.

I had found this: http://support.ipswitch.com/kb/WS-20030305-DM01.htm, stating it might be caused by a server with an incorrect time, I've gone a head and ensured all servers in my domain are synced to the forest root and have the correct time, no change.

Any thoughts?  It happens regardless of client used or operating system.

Comment: You might want to send it an inquiry to ipswitch.com.

Comment: Query sent to ipswitch...will not answer without support contract.  Sales has yet to answer as a 'new customer' query as well.